# Symfony findOneBy / findBy

Tags: doctrine, symfony

Has anyone face this strange issue with Symfony 3 (very last version)?

I have the following simple code:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getManager()
                   ->getRepository('GeneralRegistrationBundle:Service');

$service = $repository->findOneBy(array('name' => 'Registration'),array('name' => 'ASC'));

$comment = $service->getComment();
$name = $service->getName();

return new Response('le service is '. $name . ', content is ' . $comment);
```

this code works.

I purge the cache and change `findOneBy` with `findBy`:

```
$service = $repository->findBy(array('name' => 'Registration'),array('name' => 'ASC'),1 ,0);
```

then I have the following error:

> Error: Call to a member function getComment() on array

Is anybody have ideas or clues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What were you expecting?  findOne returns one and only one object.  find always returns an array of 0 or more objects.

Comment: Fuhhhh....I need to go in vacation right now....thanks Cerad

Comment: Is this solved? If so, please mark or post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`findBy()` returns an array of objects with the given conditions.

It returns an empty array if none is found. If there is only one row satisfying your condition then you can add a `[0]` at the last of your `$service` like this:

```
$service = $repository->findBy(array('name' => 'Registration'),array('name' => 'ASC'),1 ,0)[0];
```

if not, you should loop through the found array with foreach or some thing similar.

Answer (score 3):

If you want and expect one result you can use `findOneBy()` function.

```
$service = $repository->findOneBy(array('name' => 'Registration'),array('name' => 'ASC'),1 ,0)[0];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).